# XML Signature versioning of References

Tags: xml, xml-signature

Is there a, by a standard defined, way to handle versioning in Signed XML content?
To make clear what i want to do, here is my way of solving it:

```
<root>
    <Data vid="1">
         <value>123</value>
         ...
    </Data>
    <Misc vid="1">
         <value>smthng</value>
    </Misc>
    <Sigature>
         <SignedInfo>
              <Reference ref="//root/Data[@vid = '1']">
                   <DigestValue>F234D=</Digestvalue>
              </Reference>
              <Reference ref="//root/Misc[@vid = '1']">
                   <DigestValue>12dA5=</Digestvalue>
              </Reference>
         </SignedInfo>
         <SignatureValue>2828282=</SigantureValue>
     </Signature>
</root>
```

If i now change Data, substituting `<Data vid="1">` with `<Data vid = "2">` and append another Siganture like so:

```
<root>
    <Data vid="2">
         <value>CHANGED</value>
         ...
    </Data>
    <Misc vid="1">
         <value>smthng</value>
    </Misc>
    <Sigature>
         <SignedInfo>
              <Reference ref="//root/Data[@vid = '1']">
                   <DigestValue>F234D=</Digestvalue>
              </Reference>
              <Reference ref="//root/Misc[@vid = '1']">
                   <DigestValue>12dA5=</Digestvalue>
              </Reference>
         </SignedInfo>
         <SignatureValue>2828282=</SigantureValue>
         <Keyinfo />
     </Signature>
    <Sigature>
         <SignedInfo>
              <Reference ref="//root/Data[@vid = '2']">
                   <DigestValue>F234D=</Digestvalue>
              </Reference>
         </SignedInfo>
         <SignatureValue>282AFDE82=</SigantureValue>
         <Keyinfo />
     </Signature>
</root>
```

I can in my code secure the Integrity of Data and Misc by evaluating both signatures, but ignoring References that cannot be resolved anymore, in this case 
//root/Data[@vid = '1'] cannot be checked, as it does not exist anymore.

Simply resigning all content is not possible, as it must be clear, who was the last one that updated which part of the signed data.
If just Data is updated, (example would be a Client without permission to update or read Misc), only Data can be signed by a new signature, the old one has to be kept to identify the last Editor of misc.

The SignedInfo and the Reference TAG have an optional Attribute id, which is used to reference them elsewhere in the XML document, so these should not be recycled for versioning.

Another Idea i came up with was not using IDs at all, just checking all signatures, making sure that, for References that a signed multiple times, at least one signature is valid.

How is this done properly/ how does the W3C want this to be done?

Comment: Standard way for which programming language? For C# there's a [SignedXml class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If you change the XML, the signature cannot be checked any more. I guess that's the intension of applying a signature to it. With any change, you'll not find out whether the data has changed or the signature has been corrupted.

Comment: @Thomas W. in an XML signature i can check the signature for each reference seperatley. That is why every reference is hashed and all hashes are signed. I can check integrity of all hashes, and then check each hash on its own for equality with the referenced location.
I do not need an implementation in a language, i meant if W3C provided a contept on how the markup would have to look